# determine the bearing of the plane

Tags: trigonometry

A jet takes off bearing N28∘E and flies 5 miles and then makes a left (90∘) turn and flies 12 miles further. If the control tower operator wanted to locate the plane, what bearing would she use?

Answer (score 0):

Draw a picture.  The plane has flown two sides of a triangle, which is right.  You need to find the angle between the $5$ leg and the hypotenuse and add it to $N28^\circ E$